# Three.js: Merge BufferGeometries while keeping attribute position separate for each geometry

Tags: three.js

In the application I develop I am trying to combine the closest dots of the same color, dots created from a 3D coordinates vector and using Points, by using a BufferGeometry with custom positions, positions set by using the setAttribute command of the geometry and giving it a Float32BufferAttribute(positionArray, 3) object. The problem I encountered is that I have a lot of such geometries (tens of thousands usually) and since I add each one separately to the group, I have big performance issues.

So I tried to merge the buffer geometries in a single one to draw all of them at once using  BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries, but that didn't work.

How it looks without merging the geometries

[image: No merging]

How it looks with merged geometries

[image: Merged geometries]

This is how I create the geometries:

```
  const newGeometry = baseGeometry.clone();
  newGeometry.setAttribute(
    'position',
    new Float32BufferAttribute(geometryPositions, 3)
  );
  newGeometry.setAttribute(
    'color',
    new Float32BufferAttribute(geometryColors, 3)
  );
  newGeometry.computeBoundingSphere();
  geometryArray.push(newGeometry);
```

And I add them like this to my group.

```
geometryArray.forEach((e) => {
  this.group.add(new Mesh(e, baseMaterial));
});
```

This is how I merge them and add them to the group.

```
const merged = BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries(geometryArray);
this.group.add(new Mesh(merged, baseMaterial));
```

As you can see the geometries use the same material in all cases, the color being defined in the colors attribute of each geometry and vertexColors is set to true on the MeshBasicMaterial.

For a single geometry in the array, the position/color data looks like this. The sizes can be random, and the array may or may not be empty depending if the points have neighbors. The format is 3D coordinates [x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,.....].

```
const positions = {
  itemSize: 3,
  type: 'Float32Array',
  array: [
    4118.44775390625, -839.14404296875, 845.7374877929688, 4125.9306640625,
    -808.6709594726562, 856.7002563476562, 4118.44775390625,
    -839.14404296875, 845.7374877929688, 4129.93017578125, -870.6640625,
    828.08154296875,
  ],
  normalized: false,
};

const colors = {
  itemSize: 3,
  type: 'Float32Array',
  array: [
    0.9725490212440491, 0.5960784554481506, 0.03529411926865578,
    0.9725490212440491, 0.5960784554481506, 0.03529411926865578,
    0.9725490212440491, 0.5960784554481506, 0.03529411926865578,
    0.9725490212440491, 0.5960784554481506, 0.03529411926865578,
  ],
  normalized: false,
};
```

How could I improve the performance of the code above and keeping the custom positions and colors of each geometry intact?

Comment: Merging geometries is the right approach here. Do you mind demonstrating the issue with a live example? https://jsfiddle.net/u7y69dLx/

Comment: @Mugen87 unfortunately the data is non disclosable, but I provided how a single BufferGeometry looks like, I updated the question. And there are a lot of them, each form in the first pic is a BufferGeometry with such attributes, they are created in a for loop.